# Class file for "Feynman Lectures on Physics"

Tags: documentclass-writing

I have a pile of handouts and lecture notes from a course that I've been teaching every fall for a number of years, and I'm thinking of putting them together in a textbook format (I know that some people advise against writing textbooks; let's just say that I want to do this because I'll keep on teaching this course for the foreseeable future and writing a textbook now will save me time and effort in the long run). I've always thought that the *Feynman Lectures on Physics* has a really nice layout for a textbook, and I'd really like to reproduce it. I could spend sometime writing a class file that mimics this layout, but before I do that, I wanted to check if someone has done that already. A search on CTAN fails to return anything relevant, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: [Mike Gottlieb and Rudi Pfeiffer](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/contact.html) certainly have the LaTeX-Source. But maybe you could try [tufte-latex](https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) in the meantime...

Comment: I know about tufte-latex, but I would have to go into the .cls file and do some hacks to get some features I want (e.g., numbered chapters and sections, among others). I've written to Gottlieb and Pfeiffer, let's see if they are willing to share the LaTeX source.

Comment: Update: Mike Gottlieb replies: "The LaTeX manuscript of The Feynman Lectures on Physics is [...] made to support several editions having different layouts in a non-standard way - and it is proprietary. So, the answer to your question is, unfortunately, no; we don't share our LaTeX source". Dang.

Comment: *Dang*, indeed.

Comment: Package `scrlayer-notecolumn` might be of help.

Comment: In the tufte book class, you can get numbered chapters and sections by declaring `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` (for example).

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the [`sidenotes`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes)-package is a solution for you (I suspect you want to put figures and notes in the margin), it gives you a lot of the features of the `tufte-latex`-class, like `margin figures`, but it can be combined with any other `documentclass`. Here is an example using the standard `book`-class with a large outer margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[outer=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{This}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{marginfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{helix.pdf}
  \caption{Helix}
\end{marginfigure}
\blindtext[1]

\section{That}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is is possible to have configuration such that if there are no margin notes for a given page, then the margin will not occupy space (that was originally allocated)?

Comment: @blackened unfortunately this is very hard to achieve, if it is even possible. You should ask a new question!

Comment: @blackened, A nicer solution than varying the page margins might be in that case to use `wrapfigure`.