# Incorporate Tufte book style margins to standard book class

Tags: tufte, book-design

(Yes, this should be done by inspecting the document class, but I do not see myself up to the task yet.)

1) What is a straightforward method to incorporate Tufte-book-class-like margin notes to a standard book class?

2) Even though I like tweaking a lot, is it more advisable to take Tufte class as my base, and start tweaking that? (I ask because the class may not be trivial to tweak.)

Comment: I stopped using margin notes, because a colleague pointed out that it is difficult for the reader to know in what order to read them; the reader feels at sea. Now I try to make images as small and as simple as I can while still clearly visible, and put them into the flow of the text if possible, controlling the reader's flow and thereby making it easier to pay attention to the material.

Comment: @Benjamin My other concern is that the margin for margin notes takes too much room for potentially small number of side notes. I think I'll give up with this idea.

Comment: Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223250/class-file-for-feynman-lectures-on-physics/223432#223432

Answer (score 2):

1. For the standard `book` class, the [`sidenotes` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) might do the trick. You may also consider using another document class such as [`memoir`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) which, among myriad other features, provides sidenote functionality.
2. This is impossible to answer without having some idea of the tweaks you're interested in making. The [Tufte-LaTeX documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf) provides information on some customization hooks. There are [plenty of Q&As](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tufte) on this site that discuss other customizations. If you have something specific in mind, it's probably best to open a separate question to ask about it.